# How do I convert an XML RSA key to a PEM file?

Tags: xml, security, rsa, pem, xmlseclibs

I have two XML files, structured as follows:

**My Key**

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus> ... </Modulus>
  <Exponent> ... </Exponent>
  <P> ... </P>
  <Q> ... </Q>
  <DP> ... </DP>
  <DQ> ... </DQ>
  <InverseQ> ... </InverseQ>
  <D> ... </D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

**A Public Key**

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus> ... </Modulus>
   <Exponent> ... </Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I am using the `xmlseclibs` library by Robert Richards which requires a .PEM representation of the key in order to encrypt and decrypt things.

As an encryption novice, I'm not sure where to begin, and a cursory Google search did not reveal anything particularly obvious...

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that the xmlseclibs has a method `XMLSecurityKey::convertRSA` which accepts a modulus and an exponent and will create a PEM compatible public key. However, it does not seem to have any methods to create the necessary private keys.

Any help on that?

Comment: I believe the key format/presentation is from [RFC 3275, XML-Signature Syntax and Processing](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3275.txt)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a [Java utility](https://gist.github.com/ajosephau/41a339fde0cd9724675ced29dd129c5b) that can do it.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want the resulting PEM to be readable by [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org):

1. use [XMLSec2PEM](http://www.platanus.cz/blog/converting-rsa-xml-key-to-pem) tool to get a pem file
2. convert pem to pkcs8 and back (!)

The final solution I am happy with:

1. `java XMLSec2PEM my.xml > my.pem`
2. edit `my.pem` manually a bit
3. `org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.readObject()` returns `null` :-(
4. `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in my.pem -outform pem -nocrypt -out my.pkcs8`
5. `openssl pkcs8 -inform pem -nocrypt -in my.pkcs8 -out my.pkcs8.pem`
6. now `my.pkcs8.pem` is readable with the `PEMReader`

Answer (score 1):

my solution in python works like this:

1. extract modulus and exponent from xml

   ```py
   xml = etree.fromstring(key_bin)
   modulus = xml.find('Modulus').text
   exponent = xml.find('Exponent').text
   ```
2. decode them in base64 and iterate the result to save it as a
   character string of length 2:

   ```py
   mod_b64 = b64decode(modulus.encode())
   exp_b64 = b64decode(exponent.encode())
   exp = ''.join(['{:02x}'.format(x) for x in exp_b64])
   mod = ''.join(['{:02x}'.format(x) for x in mod_b64])
   ```
3. Convert the hexadecimal string to integer and generate the rsa
   public key with the rsa library:

   ```py
   exp_num = int(exp, 16)
   mod_num = int(mod, 16)
   rsa_key = rsa.PublicKey(mod_num, exp_num)
   ```
4. Finally any text can be encrypted:

   ```py
   msg_cryp = rsa.encrypt(msg.encode('ascii'), rsa_key)
   msg_cryp_str = b64encode(msg_cryp).decode('ascii')
   ```

I did this development to consume a web service which requires that an encrypted password be sent from a public key in XML format. In this way I managed to encrypt the password and consume the web service without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since xmlseclibs is PHP it seems like another PHP solution might be desirable. Here's how:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus> ... </Modulus>
  <Exponent> ... </Exponent>
  <P> ... </P>
  <Q> ... </Q>
  <DP> ... </DP>
  <DQ> ... </DQ>
  <InverseQ> ... </InverseQ>
  <D> ... </D>
</RSAKeyValue>');

$privatekey = $rsa->getPrivateKey();
$publickey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
?>
```

phpseclib has built in support for XML keys, PuTTY keys and PKCS1 keys. It'll auto detect the format and load it and getPrivateKey / getPublicKey will output PKCS1 formatted keys by default if no parameters are provided. More info:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#convert

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby version script to convert RSA to pem, vice versa.

1. Make sure Ruby has been installed.
2. start irb in your terminal

   ```
   > irb
   ```
3. Paste the following code to the irb console.

   ```
   require 'openssl'
   require 'base64'
   require 'rexml/document'

   class PKeyRSAConverter
     def initialize(from_pem:nil, from_xml:nil)
       @from_pem = from_pem
       @from_xml = from_xml
     end

     def to_xml
       xml  = '<RSAKeyValue>'
       xml += "<Modulus>#{xml_base64(xml_pkey.n)}</Modulus>"
       xml += "<Exponent>#{xml_base64(xml_pkey.e)}</Exponent>"
       xml += '</RSAKeyValue>'
       xml
     end

     def to_pem
       pem_key.to_pem
     end

     private

     def pem_key
       exponent = xml_find_exponent.to_s
       modulus = xml_find_modulus.to_s
       key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
       key.set_key(pem_base64(modulus), pem_base64(exponent), nil)
       key
     end

     def xml_find_modulus
       REXML::XPath.match(xml_document.root, "//RSAKeyValue/Modulus/text()")[0]
     end

     def xml_find_exponent
       REXML::XPath.match(xml_document.root, "//RSAKeyValue/Exponent/text()")[0]
     end

     def xml_document
       @xml_document ||= REXML::Document.new(@from_xml.to_s)
     end

     def pem_base64(string)
       Base64.urlsafe_decode64(string).bytes.inject(0){|a,e| (a << 8)| e }
     end

     def xml_pkey
       @xml_pkey ||= OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@from_pem)
     end

     def xml_base64(int)
       Base64.encode64([int.to_s(16).downcase].pack('H*')).split("\n").join
     end
   end
   ```
4. pem -> xml

   Here is an example to convert PEM to xml

   ```
   rsa_pem="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJYOlB8N/EdJL9nqEsRNF+No/9QkmPaX\n/xxpPleZTTNgakTkUlmyZPud8eEGsaX7nLgoVF39zTrXeg4hIeaWsAsCAwEAAQ==\n-----END     PUBLIC KEY-----\n"

   puts 'Convert PEM to XML'
   to_xml = PKeyRSAConverter.new(from_pem: rsa_pem).to_xml
   puts to_xml == rsa_xml
   ```
5. xml -> pem

   Here is an example to convert xml to PEM

   ```
   rsa_xml="<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>lg6UHw38R0kv2eoSxE0X42j/1CSY9pf/HGk+V5lNM2BqRORSWbJk+53x4QaxpfucuChUXf3NOtd6DiEh5pawCw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"

   puts 'Convert XML to PEM'
   to_pem = PKeyRSAConverter.new(from_xml: rsa_xml).to_pem
   puts rsa_pem == to_pem
   ```

### Reference

1. [Github Gist: anicet/pkey_rsa_converter.rb](https://gist.github.com/anicet/9dcbe32457185539d74463eaa0b1cc5c#file-pkey_rsa_converter-rb-L29-L30)

Answer (score -2):

Found this useful online tool [RSA Key Converter](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter), which supports

- XML -> PEM
- PEM -> XML

Comment: Never use online tools for this kind of sensitive information.

Comment: It can be used for public keys only.

Comment: It can be useful for publicly known private keys, that are used for demonstrations too.