# rsa sha1 encrypt using python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I want to encrypt a string using Rsa Sha1 encryption in python. I have C# code and I don't know how it is in python. please help me if you can!

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(“<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oQRshGhLf2Fh...”);
string data = "something";
 byte[] signMain = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
 sign = Convert.ToBase64String(signMain);
```

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: Start with https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/crypto/, and go from there. To save you a little time, [this is the RSA signing section](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing) of the `cryptography` documentation.

Comment: Final piece you need: `RSACryptoServiceProvider()` uses [PKCS1 padding](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md#rsa). Don't use the recommended PSS padding here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the [`cryptography` project](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) here. It has [full RSA signing support](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing). See the [cryptography section of the Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/crypto/) for alternative options.

The .NET `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object [doesn't let you set a padding algorithm](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md#rsa), it will always use PKCS1v15, so select that padding in your Python code.

First, I'd [convert that XML document to a PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094222/how-do-i-convert-an-xml-rsa-key-to-a-pem-file) so you can [load the public key from that format](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-loading). I'm not aware of any Python libraries that can load the [.NET / XKMS 2.0 XML format](https://www.w3.org/TR/xkms2/#XKMS_2_0_Section_8_2) directly:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

private_key_pem = b'-----BEGIN {format}-----\n...\n-----END {format}-----'
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    private_key_pem,
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend()
)
```

Alternatively, with a [Python XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python) you can probably feed the data from that XML document to a [`RSAPublicNumbers()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicNumbers) and [`RSAPrivateNumbers()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateNumbers) pair, then use the [`RSAPrivateNumbers.private_key()` method](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateNumbers.private_key) to produce a RSA private key object to sign with. You'll have to base64-decode the XML data and [convert from bytes to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444591/how-to-convert-a-string-of-bytes-into-an-int-in-python) using [big endian byte ordering](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-CryptoBinary).

You can then use the private key to do the signing:

```
from base64 import b64encode

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

data = "something"
signature = private_key.sign(data.encode('utf8'), padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())
signature_base64 = b64encode(signature)
```

Comment: I have following error:
AttributeError: '_RSAPrivateKey' object has no attribute 'sign' @martijn-pieters

Comment: @MaZaN: Hrm, I'll have to see what that means, exactly. I can't reproduce that error, my `cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPrivateKey` has a `sign` method.

Comment: @MaZaN: what version of `cryptography` have you got installed? The [`RSAPrivateKey.sign()` method requires version 1.4 or newer](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateKey.sign). use `import cryptography` then `cryptography.__version__` to find out. I tested this code with 2.3.1 and 2.5 (latest).